# Foreign key on myisam table alternative?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a website that need to use foreign keys, but I have searched all around and shared host doesn't support innoDB. I am using MyISAM engine. Is there an alternative for using foreign keys?

What I need:

```
table_image {
image_id (PK) 
}

table_ratings {
rating_id(PK) 
image_id(FK) 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps with some funky triggers? (I do 0% MySQL and don't understand the point of a relational database without relationships...)

Comment: In MyISAM, you have to enforce foreign key logic in client code.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html

Comment: the url article that denis gave was all about innoDB. As I said , my webhost doesn't support innoDB engine. That is why I asked if there is an alternative for MyISAM engine.

Comment: There are also alternative web hosts which don't disable standard features of MySQL. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: Are there shared webhost that has it? Did a some research and only goDaddy has it. but goDaddy's reviews are mostly 1-2 stars out of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled the hell before I fortunately switched to innoDb myself.

I had implemented all the inserts/delete cascade logic with a bunch of online/batch scripts...

But it might be ok actually, because in some very special situation you can disconnect cascade operations which is not always a bad idea reguarding to performances.

rgds.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But yea. i switched to vps that supports innodb last month.