# no foreign key in table if engine is MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

why i cannot create foreign key in my table payments.

```
crate table students(
text char(5)NOT NULL,
id int(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(250),
level varchar(250),
PRIMARY KEY (text,id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

the oder table is

```
 crate table payments(
    p_id int(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    amount varchar(250),
    id int
    PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES students(id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Switch to the InnoDB engine. Voting to close because this information is trivially available with a search .. there was a search first, right?

Comment: Because MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys.

Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769732/foreign-key-on-myisam-table-alternative

Comment: Also FYI you've got a typo - CRATE instead of CREATE

Comment: i cant change my students table into InnoDB because it has two primary keys

Answer (score 3):

Because MyISAM does not support foreign keys. The FK declarations are parsed, but otherwise ignored. You need to use InnoDB tables for real FK support.